# Adding legend icons for vector features in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am looking for ways to add legend icons for vector features in OpenLayers. I am aware that GeoExt does this and have trawled through the code - but its not at all clear to me how it functions.

Can you provide pointers to examples and/or pseudo code?

Answer (score 1):

Look through these discussion forums.  There are some demonstrations in there.

http://www.mail-archive.com/openlayers-users@lists.osgeo.org/msg01318.html

Example from that link: http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/vector-legend.html

The example has an attached JS file for you to look through too.

Comment: Actually found the complete answer here: http://sylvain.perrinel44.free.fr/wordpress/?p=396